# Create View Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-view

I am trying to create view table using **UNION ALL**. But I got one error. Below is my **SQL** code:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_DemographicInfo 
AS
(
SELECT 'HSA' AS HospitalName, HSA.*,P.*,S.*,E.*,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<18  THEN 'AGE<18'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)>=18  AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<40  THEN '18<=AGE<40'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)>=40  AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<60  THEN '40<=AGE<60'
ELSE '60<=AGE'
END AS AGE_CATEGORY
FROM  [HSA_Careman].[dbo].[ADMISSIONS] HSA
JOIN [HSA_Careman].[dbo].[PATIENTS] P ON HSA.PATIENTDBOID=P.PATIENTDBOID
JOIN [HSA_Careman].[dbo].[SEXES] S ON P.SEXDBOID=S.SEXDBOID
JOIN [HSA_Careman].[dbo].[ETHNICITIES] E ON E.ETHNICITYDBOID=P.ETHNICITYDBOID
 
UNION ALL
    
SELECT 'HTAR' AS HospitalName, HTAR.*,P.*,S.*,E.*,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<18  THEN 'AGE<18'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)>=18  AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<40  THEN '18<=AGE<40'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)>=40  AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<60  THEN '40<=AGE<60'
ELSE '60<=AGE'
END AS AGE_CATEGORY
FROM  [HTAR_Careman].[dbo].[ADMISSIONS] HTAR
JOIN [HTAR_Careman].[dbo].[PATIENTS] P ON HTAR.PATIENTDBOID=P.PATIENTDBOID
JOIN [HTAR_Careman].[dbo].[SEXES] S ON P.SEXDBOID=S.SEXDBOID
JOIN [HTAR_Careman].[dbo].[ETHNICITIES] E ON E.ETHNICITYDBOID=P.ETHNICITYDBOID
)
```

The error that I got after execute the code:

```
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'PATIENTDBOID' in view or function 'v_DemographicInfo' is specified more than once.
```

Comment: If you are creating a view, please abstain from using an asterisk in the `SELECT` statement. Not only is it “lazy”, but it leads to a number of problems as tables evolve over time. Add only the columns that you need, ensuring that each name is unique, so that the view remains consistent and reliable over time.

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: You are using `*` to add columns to a view. It can work but it's a bit sketchy. And about that, the problem here is that the column `PATIENTDBOID` is included more than once. Since the columns of a view need to have unique names, you'll need to either remove one of them, or alias it.

Comment: I see. Now I know the cause of the error. Thanks